# Good idea to check for changes in a value every XXms in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a site, which has a lot of animation, slideUps, slideDowns, etc.
There is one section which changes on('scroll') but therefore I always need the offset().top and the height() of this section … well, that's not easy because the sections above are changing their height() quite often.
So instead of triggering my resize-function each time the sections above are changing – LIKE:

```
{
   …    
   $(window).trigger('resize.mysection')
   …
}
```

… I thought it's maybe easier to update changes every XX ms … like:

```
function update_val()
{
   if ($('#mysection').offset().top != old_top)
   {
      old_top = $('#mysection').offset().top;
      $(window).trigger('resize.mysection');
   }

   //in order to save a small amount of power I would use animationframe instead of timeout
   requestAnimationFrame(update_val);
}
```

What do you guys think? Pros, Cons? Is it bad to run this small function that often?

THX!

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution is to use the `watch` method ... [click here for definition](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583).

you can then, use it like this :

```
$('#mysection').offset().watch('top', function (key, oldValue, newValue) {
    // the argument (key) has the value 'top'
    if(oldValue != newValue) {
        $(window).trigger('resize.mysection');
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, but this code may give you an idea on how to use this solution

Comment: well that sounds really interesting, but i can't get it working … would you give it a try on jsfiddle? here is mine: https://jsfiddle.net/y8zeddwy/